# What is this connector/plug called?

Tags: identification, connector, cables, plug

I have found this cable several months ago with old electronics (it is more than 5 years old, I'm sure.)

For more than a week, I have been looking for the type of plug shown in the photos on internet forums and other various sites, unfortunately without result.

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

[image: Photo 3]

Comment: What kind of equipment is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an extender cable for a gamecube controller.
See for example
[http://filthypants.blogspot.com/2018/12/?*sm_au*=iVVQ6HksVZnZsnVHL321jK0f1JH33](http://filthypants.blogspot.com/2018/12/?_sm_au_=iVVQ6HksVZnZsnVHL321jK0f1JH33)

https://hackaday.io/project/162348/gallery#63431d6a0ff5172dfb9143092610e972

Comment: Someone was too cheap to buy a wavebird